# Rotate PDF page with usePageViewController

Tags: swift, ios-pdfkit

I am working on PDFKit and try to rotate the page. It is rotating good but without using usePageViewController. With usePageViewController it won't update the frame of the page.

> ```
> // At defining PDFVIEW object
> pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
> pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
> // For rotating screen
> pdfView.currentPage?.rotation += 90
> ```

without usePageViewController pagination is not working. How to achieve both at same place.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xifjV.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUogU.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can do a trick, it works for me :).
Before changing the rotation set

```
    usePageViewController(false)
```

and after that

```
    usePageViewController(true)
```

```
guard let currentPage = self.pdfView.currentPage else {return}
self.pdfView.usePageViewController(false)
self.angle = self.angle + 90
currentPage.rotation = self.angle
self.pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
self.pdfView.autoScales = true
self.pdfView.go(to: currentPage)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is working fine.